# Is there software to visualize project timeline data?

Tags: project-management

I use WinDirStat to visualize my hard disk space and was thinking that it would be great to have something like that for some of the projects that I manage. Each project is broken up into parts with hours attached to those parts.

Is there any software out there that visualizes project data like this?

Comment: Microsoft Project can visualize time with a Gantt chart. But I don't think it will visualize exactly like WinDirStat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deltek's project management software seems to do treemaps, according to [this](http://panopticon2.moneycoach.biz/case_studies/case_deltek_vision.htm).

Here is the page of the Vision software.

http://www.deltek.com/products/vision/default.asp

**Note:** I know absolutely nothing about this software. I just found it with some googling.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Gantt chart, a graphical representation of the task components of a project, and their progress? TrackerSuite.Net offers those, as well as other reports for tracking project progress, status and costs.

Here is a page showing a Gantt chart in TrackerSuite.Net: http://www.trackersuite.net/scrn_gantt_chart.html